# Filter multiple Event Types on Pulumi AzureNative Event Grid Topic Subscription

Tags: c#, pulumi, pulumi-azure

I create Event Grid Topic Subscriptions to Service Bus Queues:

```
var args = new EventSubscriptionArgs
{
   EventSubscriptionName = topic.SubscriptionName,
   Scope = topic.Id,
   Destination = new Pulumi.AzureNative.EventGrid.Inputs.ServiceBusQueueEventSubscriptionDestinationArgs
   {
     EndpointType = "ServiceBusQueue",
     ResourceId = queue.Id
   },
};

var sub=new EventSubscription(
  topic.SubscriptionName,
  args
);
```

This works fine. Now I want to add a filter to only allow specific Event Types. According to the documentation I can add Filters like those:

```
args.Filter=new Pulumi.AzureNative.EventGrid.Inputs.EventSubscriptionFilterArgs
{
  SubjectBeginsWith="the_topic",
  SubjectEndsWith="the_topic"
}
```

But this is just one Topic, obviously. I need to be able to add an array of filters.

I expect that this can be done by `EnableAdvancedFilteringOnArrays` and `AdvancedFilters` somehow. But those properties aren't described anywhere (or I just wasn't able to find that information)

according to the [documentation](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/azure-native/api-docs/eventgrid/eventsubscription/#eventsubscriptionfilter), `AdvancedFilters` is of type `List<object>` and I did not find any information what kind of `object` is expected there to be able to add multiple filters.

Answer (score 0):

Haven’t used Pulumi, but I would suggest looking into the MSFT docs for Advanced filters [(link)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-filtering#advanced-filtering) together with the docs on the operator you want to use, in your case [stringBeginsWith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-filtering#stringbeginswith).

As you can see the filtering should be applied in a key-value manner together with the operator to be used.

Comment: Sadly this is not how Pulumi works as it has its own Wrappers around this. I cannot simply add the Azure Json

Comment: I see, but under the hood it should use the same logic eventually, so I'm thinking you should be able to use the [corresponding wrapper in Pulumi](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/azure-native/api-docs/eventgrid/eventsubscription/#stringbeginswithadvancedfilter)  which takes in a ```List<string>```. It seems to abstract away the need of providing key, value and operatorType.

Answer (score 0):

The [Pulumi docs](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/azure-native/api-docs/eventgrid/eventsubscription/#stringbeginswithadvancedfilter) were half helpful. They showed the object you need to use but forget to mention the class is in the `Pulumi.AzureNative.EventGrid.Inputs` namespace. Below is a code snippet for creating the Pulumi.AzureNative.EventGrid.EventSubscription object. The [Azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-filtering?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_EventGrid#advanced-filtering) list the different type of filters you can use.

```
Filter = new AzureNative.EventGrid.Inputs.EventSubscriptionFilterArgs
{
    IncludedEventTypes = new[]
    {
        "Microsoft.Devices.DeviceTelemetry"
    },
    AdvancedFilters = new[]
    {
        new Pulumi.AzureNative.EventGrid.Inputs.StringInAdvancedFilterArgs
        {
            OperatorType = Pulumi.AzureNative.EventGrid.AdvancedFilterOperatorType.StringIn.ToString(),
            Key= "data.MyProperty",
            Values= new[] { "MyValue" }
        }
    }
},
```